# Inverting a series

Tags: complex, series-expansion, inverse

How do I invert the following,

```
 \[Rho]=r + b0 Sum[Pochhammer[1/2, k]/(k! ((1 - q) k - 1)), {k, 0, \[Infinity]}] + b0^(1 - q)/(2 q) r^q + O[r^(2 q - 1)]
```

to get $r(\rho)$? To note, $q<0$ and $b_{0}$ is some positive constant.

Comment: Have you tried `InverseSeries`?

Comment: Yes, but it does not give any output.